# Symfony2: How to add form constraint for a field in bind PRE_SET_DATA depending on the data

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a form in Symfony 2 with basically two fields:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('contactType', 'select', array(  'choices' => $contactTypes ))
            ->add('value', 'text');
}
```

Then I added an EventSubscriber that listens to the FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA event. What I actually want to do, is to change the way of validation depending on the value of contactType (numeric values from 1 to 4, which stand for email, mobile, fixed line and fax).

I followed this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

but I can't figure out, how to add a constraint to the value field.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of adding validation constraints dynamically in event subscriber (not sure if this is even possible), you can set groups to field's validation constraints and [determine validation groups based on submitted data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html).

Comment: This is interesting but does it work with unmapped buttons ? (ie: base the validation on what button is clicked)

Answer (score 0):

A function to create the form from the controller :

```
<?php 

// ...

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param \Clicproxy\DeltadocCabBundle\Entity\Mark $mark
     * @param \Clicproxy\DeltadocCabBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
     * @return Form
     */
    private function createTagForm(Mark $mark, Tag $tag)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new TagType(), $tag, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('tag_new', array('slug' => $this->slugify($mark->getName()))),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        foreach ($mark->getFields() as $field)
        {
            $form->add($this->slugify($field->getName()), $field->getFormType(), $field->getOptions());
        }

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'crud.default.save'));

        return $form;
    }

// ...
```

The code in the entity (type, constraints, ...) :

```
<?php

// ...

/**
 * Field
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity({"name", "mark"})
 */
class Field
{

   // ...

    /**
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $options = array('label' => $this->getName(), 'mapped' => FALSE);

        $options['required'] = $this->getType() != 'checkbox';

        if ('date' == $this->getType())
        {
            $options['attr']['class'] = 'datepicker'; // 'input-group date datepicker';
            $options['attr']['data-date-format'] = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
            $options['attr']['data-date-autoclose'] = true;
        }

        if ('choice' == $this->getType())
        {
            $choices = array();
            foreach ($this->getChoices() as $choice)
            {
                $choices[$choice->getValue()] = $choice->getName();
            }
            asort($choices);
            $options['choices'] = $choices;
        }

        $options['constraints'] = $this->getValidationConstraint();

        return $options;
    }

    public function getValidationConstraint ()
    {
        $validation_constraint = array();
        if ('number' == $this->getType()) {
            if (0 < $this->getMaximum()) {
                $validation_constraint[] = new LessThanOrEqual (array(
                    'message' => 'entity.field.number.lessthanorequal', // {{ compared_value }}
                    'value' => $this->getMaximum()
                ));
            }
            if (0 < $this->getMinimum()) {
                $validation_constraint[] = new GreaterThanOrEqual(array(
                    'message' => 'entity.field.number.greaterthanorequal', // {{ compared_value }}
                    'value' => $this->getMinimum()
                ));
            }
        } elseif ('text' == $this->getType ()) {
            if (0 < $this->getMaximum()) {
                $validation_constraint[] = new Length(array(
                    'min' => $this->getMinimum() > 0 ? $this->getMinimum() : 0,
                    'max' => $this->getMaximum() > 0 ? $this->getMaximum() : 0,
                    'minMessage' => 'entity.field.text.minMessage', // {{ limit }}
                    'maxMessage' => 'entity.field.text.maxMessage',
                    'exactMessage' => 'entity.field.text.exactMessage',
                ));
            }
        } elseif ('date' == $this->getType()) {

        }

        return $validation_constraint;
    }

// ...
```

All this code work actually.

With this you have a solution to generate a form on the fly with constraints.